# Cannot load images in HTML when put in PHP document

Tags: php, html, css, image

I am new to PHP and just using it to make a login system for my HTML page. I was recently trying to make my HTML page into a PHP one so I threw all of the HTML into a PHP document and now everything works except for images. My CSS is connected to the page as well, but the background images do not work either, please help.

I am literally using images like this:

```
<img src='filepathhere'>
```

and for CSS and I am trying to use it like this for a background image:

```
body {
  background-image:url('filepathhere');
}
```

None of the images will load. I am using file paths, which I saw may be the problem, but I don't know how to make them into URLs. Either way, I have no idea how to use PHP to display the images, and nothing I have searched for online has worked so far.

[mainroute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3T9Ji.png)

[images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucsOQ.png)

[htmlimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6sjo.png)

Comment: Your broken images are nothing to do with PHP. Your paths are wrong. You should use the path relative to the web root, since that's what the browser sees.

Comment: how do I use the one relative to the web root

Comment: Post something real and perhaps we can tell you. Post your folder structure and an actual image URL that appears in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

`<img src="C:\thinkfastrap\...">` will not work when you are serving the page via a web server since `C:\thinkfastrap\...` is not in the web root so the server cannot access `C:\...`. You will need to change your image URLs to something like `/login/images/ThinkFastRapIcon.png`.

For your CSS file, URLs must be relative to the folder where the CSS file resides. So this:

```
background-image:url('foo.jpg');
```

assumes `foo.jpg` is in the same folder as the CSS file. Based on the directory structure you posted, you probably want:

```
background-image:url('/login/images/BackgroundIMG.jpg'); /* Start from docroot */
```

or:

```
background-image:url('images/BackgroundIMG.jpg'); /* Go down 1 folder to images/... */
```